# How to apply class to ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to apply a class to select box options in angularjs.

```
<div ng-controller="ExController" ng-init="init([{name:'name1',city:'city1'},{name:'name2',city:'city2'},{name:'name3',city:'city3'}])">
<select ng-model="selectedCustomer" ng-options="cust.name + '-' + cust.city for cust in customers | orderBy:'name'"></select>
</div>
```

I tried using ng-class to select tag but the class is not getting applied to options.

Comment: Please, post your code and we'll see how to help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use ng-class in select with ng-options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264051/how-to-use-ng-class-in-select-with-ng-options)

Comment: Is there a simple way other than using the directive

Comment: Is it possible for you to use CSS selectors for it? If you don't care about older browsers, you can do a lot with them: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors