# AngularJS - Add style to option

Tags: css, angularjs, html-select

**I have this code:**

```
<select ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in {{set.values}}" ng-init="set.value" ng-model="item.styles[group][name].value"></select>
```

**I need to set a style to the options like this (generated):**

```
<option style="background: green;">
<option style="background: red;">
```

How? Is it possible? Or do I need a directive or some other fancy code?

Comment: do you want generate them depends on a condition?

Comment: I have them in an object.

Answer (score -1):

You can apply conditional styles via Angular's built-in [`ng-style` directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

#### Markup

```
<span ng-style="myStyle">Sample Text</span>
```

#### Logic

```
$scope.myStyle = {
   background: '#000000'
};
```

Where the directive takes any valid expression

See also:

[How do I conditionally apply CSS styles in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813254/how-do-i-conditionally-apply-css-styles-in-angularjs)

Comment: I don't have an element to attach it on because I use "ng-options" to create option element.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264051/how-to-use-ng-class-in-select-with-ng-options