# How to use ng-class in select with ng-options in Angular 1.4 and higher

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-options, ng-class

My problem is similar to the one of the following post : [How to use ng-class in select with ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264051/how-to-use-ng-class-in-select-with-ng-options)

I want to be able to customize specific options in my `select` using CSS. If I resume the example used, I have an array of persons like this :

```
var persons = [
{Name:'John',Eligible:true},
{Name:'Mark',Eligible:true},
{Name:'Sam',Eligible:false},
{Name:'Edward',Eligible:false},
{Name:'Michael',Eligible:true}
];
```

Now I want to be able to write some code like the following to display differently one Elligible person to another not Elligible :

```
<select ng-model="Blah" ng-options="person.Name for person in persons" ng-class="{'is-elligible': person.Elligible}"></select>
```

But in this code, I don't have access to the `person` variable in the `ng-class` tag.

The thing is in the other post, the solution was based on a cutom directive which works well in angular before the 1.4. Now this solution doesn't work anymore.

A possible solution is also not to use `ng-options` but to use `ng-repeat` in an `option` tag. But I would like to still work with `ng-options` because it seems faster and easier to use.

So if anybody have any solution to do this with angular 1.4 and higher, it would be great to share it ! :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: See working sample from http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/2T757/ . I've get it from answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631325/customize-ng-options-selection-look . That's solution for Angular > 1.4

Comment: does my answer use full for you ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it with plain `ng-options`.

You should use `ng-repeat` or `custom` directive to achieve desired behaviour.  In case if case such simple as you described i recommend you using `ng-repeat` as it's common approach to achieve that behaviour.

Consider diving into details of already existed answer:
[Customize ng-options selection look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631325/customize-ng-options-selection-look?answertab=active#tab-top) and it would answer your question.

**p.s.** Didn't catch your point of using `ng-repeat`, because in particular case it's easier to use already existed directive than creating new one and adding unit tests to it, where you
've got idea that  `ng-repeat` is slower...

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. About ng-repeat, the thing is with my ng-options, I use several filters and the refresh of my filters is very very slow with ng-repeat whereas with ng-options the refresh is almost instant.