# How do I use set the same class for each option in a dropdown using ng-options in Angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dropdown menu and would like to have the options all have the same class, how is this done using AngularJS?

```
        <select options-class="rules-option" ng-init="rule.actionId" ng-class="rules-option" ng-model="rule.selectedAction" ng-options="team.name for team in teams track by team.id">
            <option value="">Select Team</option>
        </select>
```

The above code doesn't appear to set classname of any of the generated options

Comment: Just use an `ng-repeat` on an `option` element; it doesn't look like you're using any advanced features of `ng-options`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply CSS to elements

like

```
select option
{
  color:red;
  font-style:italic
}
```

If you need more generic way i would suggest refer this **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631325/customize-ng-options-selection-look)**

OR

```
<select ng-model="Blah">
      <option ng-repeat="person in persons" class="<your class>">{{person.Name}}</option>  
    </select>
```

Here is the **[Sample](http://embed.plnkr.co/WMbyQvfeMnp4YPn6uH9L/)**