# Bind to a single html element of the select-tag

Tags: angularjs

How can I format a single element in the select list? For example I want to bind the `schoolclassCode.color` property to a html-element and its background attribute.

```
<select size="10" 
        class="form-control" 
        multiple 
        ng-model="activeStep.selectedSchoolclassCodes"
        ng-options="i.schoolclassCode for i in activeStep.schoolclasses">
</select>
```

Comment: its not clear what you are asking, do you want to access any option element generated by ng-repeat ?

Comment: Yes I would like to format each ng-repeat element by binding an elements style background property to my array schoolclasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution:

```
<select ng-model="activeStep.selectedSchoolclassCodes">
              <option ng-repeat="item in activeStep.schoolclasses" style="background: rgb({{item.color}})" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.schoolclassCode}}</option>
            </select>
```

Now every option is rendered with a bound background color :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it is possible to add element styles to option elements generated by ng-options. But you can add a class conditionally to all the options like this.

```
<select ng-model="foo" ng-options="x.name for x in items" 
   options-class="{ 'ClassForColor' : BooleanVariable, 'ClassForDifferentColor': !BooleanVariable}"></select>
```

here `ClassForColor` and `ClassForDifferentColor` are css classes for setting your css styles, which will be set to your options depending on value of  `BooleanVariable`.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264051/how-to-use-ng-class-in-select-with-ng-options) you can find some more information.

Comment: "I don't know whether it is possible to add element styles to option elements generated by ng-options." But this is what I exactly asked for.