# Adding style to ng-option on condition with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am using the following code to render a select where the options are rendered with ng-options:

```
 <select ng-options="cat.id as cat.name for cat in categories">
       <option  value="" selected="selected">Default Option...</option>
 </select>
```

and I need to add a CSS style option (namely font-weight:bold) only to options that have paricular ids. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to style your options, consider using

```
<option
    ng-repeat="cat in categories"
    ng-value="{{ cat.id }}"
    ng-bind="cat.name"
    ng-style="cat.style"></option>
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I need to use the ng-options directive

Comment: Then you need to create a directive. Check this SO thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264051/how-to-use-ng-class-in-select-with-ng-options