# Not able to apply class to ng-options or options in selectbox

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a selectbox with a reset button which resets the value to default.

I tried this with `ng-options` and without it, following plunk have the code:

With `ng-options`: [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/JuHr4lCVmuCLm4djFgyh?p=preview)

Without `ng-options`: [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/UcifBwkvffEzMJCQDfVn?p=preview)

Now the reset button works perfectly fine in both of them but I want to customize the select CSS and I have added classes for it but somehow it's not working, I want the select box to look something like this:

[image]

I am using `bootstrap` with some customization for CSS.

This [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264051/how-to-use-ng-class-in-select-with-ng-options) is quite similar to my problem but they are applying CSS to the values however, I want the selectbox to be customized.

Comment: please create plunker with customize css.

Comment: The css added to `select-order` class in the css for the selectbox which works fine if I write it in `style` attribute rather than `class` but when the dropdown opens up, I want this CSS `padding: 3px 20px; line-height: 1.42857143;`, I don't know how to show it

Comment: you cant style dropdownlist except the color change with html select. You need to create your own module or try ui-select

Comment: @Alaksandar: I am trying with `ui-select` but the `model` is not updating, here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv9mo66a/489/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv9mo66a/491/

Comment: You need to initiate the selected as a object. I missed it out. Here is the revised version without using on-select. jsfiddle.net/Lv9mo66a/493

Comment: @Alaksandar: That does the job, thanks!